# Phonegap - C++ Library

Tags: iphone, android, c++, java-native-interface, cordova

I'm planning to write an application for Android and iOS and I want to use Phonegap for it . Now I've heard, that I can write native modules which are then included in the build process

I've seen modules which use normal objective c/Java code.

Is it possible to write a plugin with a .mm file and a .h file where the .mm file includes some c++ headers and calls its functions ?

And the same for Android, where I can use JNI to use the C++ code in the java file ?

I don't even need clear instructions, just a yes or no because I don't know if I should put more effort in that direction ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible. Refer Phonegapdelegate.m, YouAppDelegate.m and .h files for more information.

Regarding android, refer [Javascript interface in webview](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).